# multiple problems with vmrun.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, automation, vmware

Host: Windows 7 pro 64-bit with VMWare Workstation 7.1

What I am trying to automate:

```
1) Clone a template into a new VM. The template is Windows Server 2003 32-bit w/SP1 and already has VMWare tools installed and network and VM settings configured the way I want.
2) Start the VM
3) Copy a batch file and a zip file into the VM which installs a build and copies some files into certain locations. The build is different each time but I want the OS to be the same each time.
4) Run the batch file within the VM
```

The basic idea is to be able to deploy different versions of the build into a VM with a controlled OS image and configuration.

my batch file looks something like:

```
     vmrun clone %vm_template_path% %new_vm_path% full
     vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> start %new_vm_path% gui
     vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> copyFileFromHostToGuest %new_vm_path% %file_on_host% %file_path_on_VM%
     vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> runProgramInGuest %new_vm_%path% -nowait -interactive %file_on_host%
```

The clone works just fine. My problem(s) are:
1) The start command does properly startup the VM, but never returns to the next line in my batch file. I waited over 30 minutes to ensure.
2) The copyFileFromHostToGuest does not copy the file, never returns or display any errors. It just sits there. The file I tried to copy as a test was 30KB and I waited 15 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem could be that the start command is active the entire time the VM is turned on. Have you tried calling it in a separate batch file?

```
vmrun clone %vm_template_path% %new_vm_path% full

REM Creates a separate batch to run the start command which will delete itself when done
ECHO vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> start %new_vm_path% gui > startVM.bat
ECHO del /q /s /f startVM.bat >> startVM.bat

REM runs the separate batch
startVM.bat

REM if the VM needs to be booted before you continue with the file copy you can try a TIMEOUT in here like the two minute one below:
TIMEOUT 120

vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> copyFileFromHostToGuest %new_vm_path% %file_on_host% %file_path_on_VM%
vmrun -T ws -gu <user> -gp <pass> runProgramInGuest %new_vm_%path% -nowait -interactive %file_on_host%
```

Comment: I tried this out today and didn't help. I even tried manually starting the VM and then running the copyFileFromHostToGuest command but it still gets stuck. I went through the logs created in the temp directory but they have nothing. I gave up this method, so instead my batch file mounts a shared directory on the VM after cloning/starting it and then uses WMI+batch file to do the rest. Thanks for the help however.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it on a computer with 32 bit Windows as host OS?
I had the same problem, after opening a support case and lots of error searching it turned out to be a problem with Panda Antivirus on 64 bit windows blocking VMRun. So I either had to change Antivirus or use 32 bit Windows.

Comment: Sorry, actually I kind of gave this up and instead moved to VirtualBox which allowed me to do the same thing.